# Bulk insert fixed length file with ragged right lines

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I have a fixed length text file, except some of the lines end early, with a carriage return/line feed.  I'm using a .fmt file.

Q: How do I tell SQL Server to use an empty string for the fields that are unaccounted for?

I should probably ask my client to pad his text file, but it would be easier to just process it with the lines that are terminated early.

Comment: I just wrote a pre-processor to condition the text file before doing the bulk insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write a pre-processor to condition the text file before doing the bulk insert.